# Need shares of a particular level by Partner

Tags: r

My data frame has 3 columns, the first contains names of different partners and the second contains different levels (all partners have all levels) The third column contains the volume of that particular level with that partner. It looks like this

```
Partner | Level | Volume  
a       | 32    | 213  
b       | 32    | 450  
c       | 24    | 56
a       | 24    | 213
```

I want to add a column that displays the share of the particular level in a partner. For example, the additional column in the above example would read 50% for both rows with partner a and 100% for the rest. I tried a for loop like this

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df) {
  for (a in partners) {
    if (df$Partner[i] == a) {
      df$Share[i] <- df$Volume[i] / filter(aggregate(.~Partner, df, sum), Partner %in% i)$Volume
      break
    }
  }
}
```

There is no error, but the data frame remains unchanged. What am I doing wrong, and is there any other way to do this better? Because I'll be performing this on a very large dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in base R :

```
df <- data.frame(Partner = c("a", "b", "c", "a"), Level = c(32, 32, 24, 23), Volume = c(213, 450, 56, 213))

df$Share <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(k) df$Volume[k] / sum(df$Volume[df$Partner[k] == df$Partner]))*100
df

  Partner Level Volume Share
1       a    32    213    50
2       b    32    450   100
3       c    24     56   100
4       a    23    213    50
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly straightforward base R solution would be to compute a frequency table of `Partner`, divide 1 by each frequency, and then merge it with the original dataframe

```r
Share <- as.data.frame(1/table(df$Partner))
names(Share) <- c("Partner", "Share")
df <- merge(df, Share, by = "Partner")

#### OUTPUT ####

  Partner Level Volume Share
1       a    32    213   0.5
2       a    24    213   0.5
3       b    32    450   1.0
4       c    24     56   1.0
```

Another, cleaner solution might be to use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(Partner) %>% 
    mutate(Share = 1/n())

#### OUTPUT ####

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Partner [3]
  Partner Level Volume Share
  <chr>   <int>  <int> <dbl>
1 a          32    213   0.5
2 b          32    450   1  
3 c          24     56   1  
4 a          24    213   0.5
```